# Action on click when plotting with imagesc

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I have created a GUI with several plots. On some I have 1D histograms, and vertical lines that change position as I click on the plot. Just as an example here is a line assigned to a plot:

```
lines.L1 = line([0.01 0.01],[0 max(e1)],'Color','red');
set(lines.L1,'parent',handles.plot_e1);
```

And in the callback function I just change the 'XData' and 'YData' and replot the line. Relatively simple.

My question is, why can't I do this for a plot in which I have imaged a 2D histogram ("heatmap" I suppose) using the 'imagesc' function? Before plotting my clicking to move lines works just fine, but once I plot using imagesc nothing happens, no error messages or anything. In fact the callback function doesn't run at all.

Is there a better way to plot a 2D histogram with a colour legend that will allow me to use the callback function just like I could for the 1D histograms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you've bound your callback to the `ButtonDownFcn` of the `axes` and the `imagesc` object *covers up the `axes` and has it's own `ButtonDownFcn`*. You can either assign your callback to the image's `ButtonDownFcn` as well

```
him = imagesc(data);
set(him, 'ButtonDownFcn', @callback)
```

Or you can instruct the `image` object to not respond to a button press by turning the `HitTest` property to `'off'`

```
him = imagesc(data);
set(him, 'HitTest', 'off')
```